# SAS -- Read first and last observation of multiple csv files

Tags: csv, input, file-io, sas, eof

I want to read the first and last record of a huge number of .csv files (several gigabytes) stored in one folder on a Linux machine. Suppose they are called `have1.csv, have2.csv, ...` and so on.

So I tried the following code, which only gives me the first line. But not the last line.

```
%let datapath = ~/somefolder/;    
data want;

length finame $300.;
/*Reference all CSV files in input data folder*/
infile "&datapath.have*.csv" delimiter="," 
        MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 
        eov=eov eof=eof filename=finame end=done;

/*Define input format of variables*/
informat Var1 COMMA. Var2 COMMA. Var3 COMMA.;
/*Loop over files*/
do while(not done);

    /*Set trailing @ to hold the input open for the next input statement 
      this is because we have several files */
    input @;

    /*If first line in file is encountered eov is set to 1,
      however, we have firstobs=2, hence all lines would be skipped. 
      So we need to reset EOV to 0.*/
    if eov then
    do;
        /*Additional empty input statement 
         handles missing value at first loop*/
        input;
        eov = 2;
    end;
    /*First observation*/
    if eov=2 then do;
        input Var1--Var3;
        fname=finame;
        output;
        eov = 0;
    end;

        /*Last observation*/
       if 0 then do;
          eof:      input Var1--Var3;
                    fname=finame;
                    output;
        end;
        input;

end;
stop;

run;
```

I would very much appreciate your help! If I have misunderstood the concept or the interplay of infile, end, eov, eof and input @, please tell me! I do not know where my mistake is...

Comment: Are you also trying to skip header lines? Is that what the comment about FIRSTOBS= option is about?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not writing back earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use wildcards in the INFILE statement you can use the EOV= option to create a variable that will flag when a new file starts. Note that you need to manually reset the EOV flag.

Read and hold the line before reading the values so that you can test if a new file has started. That way you can output the last line from the previous file. You will also need to RETAIN your input variables so that the values from the last line of the previous file are available.

You also need to use the END= option to be able to output the last line of the last file.

Example:

```
data want ;
  retain filename str;
  length fname filename $200 ;
  infile '/dir1/file*' filename=fname eov=eov end=eof truncover ;
  input @;
  if eov then output;
  filename=fname ;
  input str $30. ;
  if _n_=1 or eov or eof then output;
  eov=0;
run;
```

Example output:

```
Obs    filename       str
 1     /dir1/file1    Line1
 2     /dir1/file1    Line3
 3     /dir1/file2    Line1
 4     /dir1/file2    line4
 5     /dir1/file3    Line1
 6     /dir1/file3    Line3
```

If you want to skip first line of each file (the header line) add this statement right after the `input @;` statement.

```
if _n_=1 or eov then input;
```

Note you will need to adjust the logic if it is possible that your input files do not all have at least two data lines (three lines counting header line).

Comment: This is a great answer, in the case that I had CSV files that do not contain a header row with the variable names in it. Unfortunately, mine have... sorry for not making that clear enough. 

But: Is there a way to skip the first observation in each file so that the PDV does not receive the input from the header information in the first line? In this case I think your solution with the retain statement would actually work...

Comment: end= options seems to only catch last line of last file. Anyway you proved no while loop needed, thanks.

Comment: It is not hard to skip the header lines. Use the EOV flag to know when you need to skip.

Comment: Yes. the END and FIRSTOBS options will apply to the aggregated file and not to the individual files. To process the individual files separately start with a list of filenames and use the FILEVAR= option to dynamically specify the filename to read. Then you could use the FIRSTOBS= and END= options to find the first and last record.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me, please try it:

```
data want;

length finame $300.;
/*Reference all CSV files in input data folder*/
infile "E:\temp\test\have*.txt" delimiter="," 
        MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767
        eov=eov filename=finame end=done;

        /* Note: firstobs option seems to work on first file only */

/*Define input format of variables*/
informat Var1 COMMA. Var2 COMMA. Var3 COMMA.;

input; /* skip header in first file */

input Var1--Var3; /* read first real record in first file */
fname=finame;
output;

/* Loop over files*/
do while(not done);

   input @;/* try input do determine eov condition */

   if eov then do;/* new file detected - we're on header record, but variables contain values from previous record - see "read values" */
      output; /* variables contain values from previous record - output those values */
      input; /* skip header */
      eov = 0;
      input Var1--Var3; /* read first real observation */
      fname=finame;
      output; /* first line of new file */
   end;

    input Var1--Var3; /* read values - it might be last record */
end;
output; /* output last record of last file */
run;
```

Actually, as Tom below describes, there's no need for while loop (dangerous thing :-) ).
I've modified the code now:
(need to add RETAINs because we're looping in data step itself)

```
data want;

length finame $300.;
/*Reference all CSV files in input data folder*/
infile "E:\temp\test\have*.txt" delimiter="," 
        MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767
        eov=eov filename=finame end=done;

informat Var1 COMMA. Var2 COMMA. Var3 COMMA.;
retain Var1 Var2 Var3 fname;
if _N_ = 1 then do; /* first file */
   input; /* skip header in first file */
   input Var1--Var3; /* read first real record in first file */
   fname=finame;
   output;
end; 

input @; /* try input do determine eov condition */

if eov then do; /* new file detected - we've moved past header record, but variables contain values from previous record - see "read values" */
   output; /* variables contain values from previous record - output those values */
   input; /* skip header */
   eov = 0;
   input Var1--Var3; /* read first real observation */
   fname=finame;
   output; /* first line of new file */
end;
else input Var1--Var3;
if done then output;
run;
```

Comment: This works, great. The trick with inputting each line, but only outputting the last, didn't occur to me... nicely done! Thanks! :D

Comment: Sorry. I cannot grant two answers. Tom is right. His code is a little clearer. But yours works nice as well. I am torn...Thanks for the great help you guys are! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of files then the code is clearer.  For example if you can use PIPE engine you could use ls (or Dir) command to get filenames.  Then use FILEVAR= option to dynamically read each individual file.

```
data want ;
  infile 'ls ~/test/dir1/file*' pipe truncover ;
  input fname $200.;
  filename=fname;
  infile csv filevar=fname dsd truncover firstobs=2 end=eof ;
  do _n_=1 by 1 while (not eof);
     input str :$30. ;
     if _N_=1 or eof then output;
  end;
run;
```

Or if your files are large you could take advantage of using PIPE to use `head` and `tail` commands to find the beginning and ending of each file without needing to have SAS read the whole file.  You would probably need to test to see if it actually improved the performance.

```
data want ;
  infile 'ls ~/test/dir1/file*' pipe truncover ;
  input filename $200.;
  length cmd1 cmd2 $200 ;
  cmd1='head -2 '||filename ;
  infile top pipe filevar=cmd1 dsd truncover firstobs=2 end=eof1 ;
  if  (not eof1) then do;
     input str :$30. ;
     output;
  end;
  cmd2='tail -1 '||filename ;
  infile bottom pipe filevar=cmd2 dsd truncover firstobs=1 end=eof2;
  if  (not eof2) then do;
     input str :$30. ;
     output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: The head and tail solution is not faster. Way slower. Had to adjust it with a find command `"cd ~/thepath; find . type -f -name ""*.csv"" -print"` to generate the list...